# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle - TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Im tryig to learn how the TableViewController works but I get an error every time I try to run my little test app.

It shows me the following error:

Error:

> TabelViewSB[13074:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /Users/xxxx/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/
>   Applications/F8138200-E111-40BA-8C0C-0B42E91A5312/TabelViewSB.app 
>   (loaded)' with name 'Storyboard''

Code TableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Code TableViewController.m :

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zeile %i",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

What I did:

- created new project -> empty App
- created a Storyboard (Main Interface is chanced to Storyboard)
- add a TabelViewController to the Storyboard
- created a new class "TableViewController" to mess with it...

I read a lot in the forum about that problem and tried given solutions:
(didn`t work... )

- Product -> Clean  (pressed ↑,cmd,K)
- deleted derived data
  ... also I tried
- to add the bundle ... but I didn't get it...

I would be really thankful if someone has a little hint for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: solved the first problem by resetting the iOS Simulator  with iOS Simulator -> Content and Preferences reset

Comment: please paste the code where you initialize the tableviewcontroller..

Comment: Your array has 30 objects? if it is less than 30 it can give some error because of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rename some of the files outside of XCode? For example in Finder? If so, you need to rename them back.

For the future: It is usually a bad thing to change anything in your project outside of XCode. It will take care of almost anything for you.

Comment: It could be come extra spaces with nib name  when registering your tableViewcell

Answer (score 1):

please give reusable identifier of cell in your TableViewController as  "Cell" in storyboard
Hope this will solve your problem.